# Query in codeigniter model doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

This function in my model is intended to validate if the student user inserted a correct credential. I doubt it's the structure of my query that is problematic. Here's my code segment:

**index.php** (view)

```
            <form method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('home/validateStud');?>" name="formvalidate">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idnum" placeholder="ID Number"/>
                <br>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" placeholder="PASSWORD"/>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%;" onclick="" name="submit2" value="<?php echo $this->uri->uri_string(); ?>" id="validated">Validate</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

**home.php** (controller)

```
public function validateStud()
{
  $submit=$this->input->post('submit2');
  $studentId=$this->input->post('idnum');
  $password=$this->input->post('pass');
  $this->load->model('StudentModel', 'Student', true);

  $valid=$this->Student->checkValidation($studentId, $password);
  if (isset($_POST['submit2']) && $valid) {
    redirect('student/index', true);
  }
  else
  {
    $indication = $this->initializeDialogBox('Record not found', ' Student Validation', 'fa-primary', 'fa-user', 'danger');
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $indication);
    redirect($this->input->post('submit2'));  
  }
}
```

**studentmodel.php** (model)

```
public function checkValidation($studentId, $password)
    {
        $query="SELECT * from STUDENT WHERE STUDENT_ID='".$studentId."' AND PASSWORD='".$password."'";
        $queryValid=$this->db->query($query)->row();

        if($queryValid->num_rows == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

`initializeDialogBox()` is a declared function by me, so don't mind it. Thanks in advance for those who can help me. :)

Comment: `num_rows` is actually a function, so you should call it like this `$queryValid->num_rows()`. Have you tried running your query directly in mysql (or whatever you use) ?

Comment: Actually, no error comes out. It's just that it always return false even if I keep on entering correct id and password. There's also no error in my database connection.

Comment: @sandddyyyy try now with my answer...

Comment: I've been trying hard and now I think I already messed my code up.

Comment: Is it okay if I show you guys my view, controller and model codes for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function checkValidation($studentId, $password)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * from STUDENT WHERE STUDENT_ID='".$studentId."' AND PASSWORD='".$password."'";
        $queryValid = $this->db->query($query)->row(); // it has data of that row

        if($this->db->query($query)->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public function checkValidation($studentId, $password)
{

    $q=$this->db->get_where('STUDENT',array('STUDENT_ID'=>$studentId,'PASSWORD'=>$password));

    if ($q->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    $query = $this->db->get_where('STUDENT',array('STUDENT_ID'=>$studentId, PASSWORD'=>$password))->row();
    $num_rows = $this->db->get_where('STUDENT',array('STUDENT_ID'=>$studentId, PASSWORD'=>$password))->num_rows();

    if($num_rows>0){
       return true;
    }else{
       return false;
    }
```